# Use Actors to send data to Akka websockets

Tags: java, http, websocket, akka, akka-http

I am using [Akka websockets](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/java/http/server-side/websocket-support.html) to push data to some client.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.http.javadsl.ConnectHttp;
import akka.http.javadsl.Http;
import akka.http.javadsl.ServerBinding;
import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpRequest;
import akka.http.javadsl.model.HttpResponse;
import akka.http.javadsl.model.ws.Message;
import akka.http.javadsl.model.ws.WebSocket;
import akka.japi.Function;
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Sink;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Source;

public class Server {

  public static HttpResponse handleRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Handling request to " + request.getUri());
    if (request.getUri().path().equals("/greeter")) {
      final Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeterFlow = greeterHello();
      return WebSocket.handleWebSocketRequestWith(request, greeterFlow);
    } else {
      return HttpResponse.create().withStatus(404);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();

    try {
      final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

      final Function<HttpRequest, HttpResponse> handler = request -> handleRequest(request);
      CompletionStage<ServerBinding> serverBindingFuture = Http.get(system).bindAndHandleSync(handler,
          ConnectHttp.toHost("localhost", 8080), materializer);

      // will throw if binding fails
      serverBindingFuture.toCompletableFuture().get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      System.out.println("Press ENTER to stop.");
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    } finally {
      system.terminate();
    }
  }

  public static Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeterHello() {
    return Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore(),
        Source.single(new akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.TextMessage.Strict("Hello!")));
  }
}
```

At the client side, I am successfully receiving a 'Hello!' message.
However, now I want to send data dynamically (preferably from an Actor), something like this:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class PushActor extends UntypedActor {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof String) {
      String statusChangeMessage = (String) message;
      // How to push this message to a socket ??
    } else {
      System.out.println(String.format("'%s':\nReceived unknown message '%s'!", selfActorPath, message));
    }
  }

}
```

I am unable to find any example regarding this online.

The following is the software stack being used:

- Java 1.8
- [akka-http 10.0.10](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http_2.11/10.0.10)

Answer (score 0):

One - not necessarily very elegant - way of doing this is to use `Source.actorRef` and send the materialized actor somewhere (maybe a router actor?) depending on your requirements.

```
public static Flow<Message, Message, NotUsed> greeterHello() {
    return Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(Sink.ignore(),
        Source.actorRef(100, OverflowStrategy.fail()), 
        Keep.right()).mapMaterializedValue( /* send your actorRef to a router? */);
}
```

Whoever receives the actorRefs of the connected clients must be responsible for routing messages to them.